# \left ... \right make different sizes in numerator and denominator

Tags: fractions, size

I noticed that the commands \left\| ... \right\| don't always generate brackets of the same size, even when the content is the same. Example:

The code `\frac{\left\|A^{-1}\right\|}{\left\|A^{-1}\right\|}` yields this:

[image]

Clearly, the bars are larger in the numerator, although the code is identical. Is there a nice way to prevent this?

Comment: I recommend you to use `\bigl \bigr` or `\Bigl \Bigr` instead.

Comment: But this is slightly annoying. \left and \right exist precisely so I don't have to think about size all the time. Isn't there any way to automate this such that same content gives same size brackets?

Comment: I'd even drop left/right here, there is no need for them

Comment: @Frank that is not correct, autoscaling should be left for certain situations, for example this looks bad: `\left(\sum_j \right)`, you'll also often run into problems when used in text mode, they grow too large and disturb line spacing.

Comment: I don't obtain this result. Could you please post a full code reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the denominator is set in "cramped" style in which the exponent is lower, which has an effect on the left-right size, it is often best to use manual size `\left\right` has an adverse effect on horizontal spacing, even when it does not stretch the delimiters.
here you could use `\bigl\|`  or simply `\|`

Comment: Much better is `\lVert` and `\rVert`

Comment: @egreg I wondered about mentioning that but separate issue and while they are better in general, not going to make any difference here is it, with just a single term

Answer (score 3):

I simply add a response to generate brackets of the same size. I hope my code is clear. If there are some comments I am available.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{\norm{A^{-1}}}{\norm{A^{-1}}}\]
\end{document}
```